# Find points within a distance using MySQL

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have a MySQL table

```
Users(State, City, Zip, Lat, Long)
```

I would like to get a list of user who are inside the circle or square of a given latitude and longitude with given distance. For example my input Lat= 78.3232 and Long = 65.3234 and distance = 5 kilometers. I would like to get the list of users who are inside 5 kilometers distance from the point 78.3232 and 65.3234. Is it possible to solve this with single query?

Answer (score 1):

## Using GIS

Assuming MySQL 8+

```
SELECT u.*,
  ST_Distance(
    ST_SRID(Point(65.3234, 78.3232),4326), 
    ST_SRID(Point(u.lon,u.lat),4326)
  )
FROM Users AS u
WHERE ST_Intersects(
  ST_Buffer(ST_SRID(Point(65.3234, 78.3232),4326), 5000), 
  ST_SRID(Point(u.lon,u.lat),4326)
);
```

If you're not using MySQL 8+ you can't use `ST_SRID(geom,SRID)`. Also, if you store `GEOMETERY` types on the table, rather than silly `lat` and `long` columns, this looks a lot cleaner.

```
SELECT u.*,
  ST_Distance(
    ST_SRID(Point(65.3234, 78.3232),4326), 
    u.geom
  )
FROM Users AS u
WHERE ST_Intersects(
  ST_Buffer(ST_SRID(Point(65.3234, 78.3232),4326), 5000), 
  u.geom
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic query would be the following:

```
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude
FROM   users
WHERE  (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((latitude*pi()/180)) + cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((($lng - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*2.133) <= $distance;
```

For your example:

```
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude
FROM   users
WHERE  (((acos(sin((78.3232*pi()/180)) * sin((78.3232*pi()/180)) + cos((78.3232*pi()/180)) * cos((78.3232*pi()/180)) * cos(((65.3234 - longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*2.133) <= 5;
```

You must be aware that this is not the most optimized query if you have a lot of data because of the amount of computation, but it works. There is some ways to improve the overall execution of that query but it's another topic.

Comment: Than k you , i will see and get back to u , how it will work